# ¿como mandar un evento en laravel 5.5 utilizando la libreria pusher.js?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, nodejs

estoy intentando realizar notificaciones en tiempo real con laravel y pusher.js el problema es que cuando creo el evento no me llega al cliente pero no me marca ningun error codigo : 
[image: este es el script de mi cliente esperando una notificacion]

[image: aca creo el evento]

[image: aca esta la clase]

[image: cuando ejecuto mi proyecto se conecta al canal de pusher]

ya edite los archivos de serviceProvider, broadCasting, app.php , .env al igual de instalar el pusher con compuser y el npm ¡¡

alguna solucion se los agradezco ¡¡?

---

agradecería tu ayuda ¡¡aca estan las capturas de los archivos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [ask], para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero rellenar tu .env con los valores

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

luego el config/broadcasting.php (las KEY no las puse, ademas se suelen poner en el ENV)

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'eu',
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],
```

En el controlador tienes que enviar el evento asi

```
event(new LanzarEvent($datos));
```

despues lanzar el comando `php artisan make:event`

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class LanzarEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $datos;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($datos)
    {
        $this->datos= $datos;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('lectura');
    }

}
```

y para leerlo en la vista

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/pusher.js') }}"></script>
<script>
        Echo.private('lectura')
            .listen('LanzarEvent', (e) => {
               // Tu metodo
            });
</script>
```

Comment: buenas tardes , ya lo hice y al momento de crear el evento no me arroja ningún error pero tampoco ningún mensaje !! no se que pueda tener mal ,adjunto la clase web y la clase event

Comment: El event esta bien, pero como lo recoges en la vista no, sigue mi ejemplo y no sigas tutoriales antiguos dado que en >5.4 cambio el broadcasting. También en config/app descomenta 
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,

Comment: ya encontré el error estaba en la parte del cliente en el script no estaba tomando el evento del mismo nombre al que se enviaba¡¡ muchas gracias por la respuesta